# Doctrine Refactor entities

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Hello i am using Doctrine ORM, i have major problem. Overall i have 10 tables, each table has it's own address fields(street, city, state, zip). So basically i am trying to refactor db structure, and created one new address table with those fields, old tables will hold address_id as a reference, and i will remove address fields from each table, and migrate data.

Since it's very big project with large code base trying to determine whats the best approach to do this refactoring regarding entities.

Things to concern

1. find() method
2. findBy() method
3. persist
4. Query Builder

Here it's my userCreditCard entity, it has address object in it, and that object should be replaced with "address_id".

```
class UserCreditCard extends LoggableEntity implements UserCreditCardInterface
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var int|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $userId;


    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="cc_number", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $ccNumber;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="cc_name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $ccName = '';

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="cc_date", type="date", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $ccDate;

    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="bill_addr_type", type="boolean", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $billAddrType = false;

    /**
     * @var UserBillingAddress
     * @ORM\Embedded(class = "\Cae\User\Dal\Entity\Embeddable\UserBillingAddress", columnPrefix=false)
     */
    protected $address;
```

Here is address object.

```
/** @ORM\Embeddable */
class UserBillingAddress extends AbstractAddressEmbeddable
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="bill_street_address", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $address = '';

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="bill_street_address2", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $address2 = '';

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="bill_city", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $city = '';
```

My question would be since it's very large project is it possible to some how override with entity listeners or with magic setter so for example when someone do

```
$this->userCreditCardRepository->find($id);
```

pull address data from new Address table (i can't do joins since address table lives in another module, so i have to use public services).

Maybe to override find, findBy and other methods in AbstractRepository, but i am not sure what the best approach? Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: Doctrine's [embeddable](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/tutorials/embeddables.html) functionality stores embedded objects directly in the entity table.  So your example is a non-starter.  I don't think Doctrine 3 even supports embeddable anymore though I could be wrong on that.  Why exactly can't you do a regular join and just establish a relationship?  Your address table is in a completely different database?

Comment: plan is to use microservices, so no joins between modules